# Error restoring RSA private key on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, openssl, rsa, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I use encription in my app. I store private key as bytes array and use the following code to restore it:

```
PrivateKey private = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(s_privateKeyIn1t));
```

It works perfectly on all my target android platforms 2.1 -> 4.0.4, but fails on Jelly Bean!

Jelly Bean throws an exception:

```
07-20 17:29:35.197: E/AnyBalance:Codec(990): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
07-20 17:29:35.197: E/AnyBalance:Codec(990):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.d2i_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO(Native Method)
07-20 17:29:35.197: E/AnyBalance:Codec(990):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:73)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It could be a bug in your build, does it run on ICS?

Comment: From what it says [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) 4.04 is not Jelley Bean, its Ice Cream Sandwhich, I would edit your post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 23):

[This is the code](http://hi.baidu.com/wuuubo/item/fe48e77415ca893a71442396) that worked for me (the second line is the important part):

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(s_privateKeyIn1t);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);
```

Comment: KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","BC");   working. You saved my day.

Comment: You saved my life bro by adding "BC". But what does it means?

Comment: "BC" is the cryptographic service provider. Which refers to a package or set of packages that supply a concrete implementation of a subset of the JDK Security API cryptography features.

Comment: For Android OS 6.0 and below versions 'KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","BC")' this line is working, and for above 6.0 'KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")' this line is working. But why KeyFactory instance has differed for different android versions? any idea?

Comment: Saved my day with "BC"

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know the reason why it has happened but I've figured out how to deal with it. I have just reencoded the key on previous android version and this reencoded key worked on Jelly Bean.

I used the following code to reencode the key:

```
Private key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(s_privateKeyIn1t));
byte [] xxx = s_privateKey.getEncoded(); //Then I watched this byte array in debugger and inserted it in a source code.
//Now it works on Jelly Bean
```